# Possible to Execute AJAX Executing PHP in External File?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Is it possible to retrieve an external file (database) via link or form ( example.php) with ajax, then execute any php code within that file, which in turn displays it to the user?

Thanks,
Bart

Comment: what is excellently you want ?

Comment: I think the answer is probably "Yes"

Comment: Can you please give some more information about this? What you need exactly? What do you mean external file via link? Whether it returns any data or have to manipulate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking to use ajax to retrieve the php file and execute it after retrieving it, I think the answer is  "no".  The ajax is client side, and the php is server side.  You CAN however call the php file FROM the jquery using .GET or .POST, process it with the data supplied, and return the results TO the ajax function to display it however you'd like.  There are thousands of simple examples if you google it.